# Java - how to deserialize into a logically identical class?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I don't want to go into too much detail, so I'll try to boil it down as simple as I can. We've got an app (Java, Spring Boot) that generates some information which we then serialize and store in a database. To serialize it, we use ObjectMapper:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(); // default to using DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);

manifestJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(manifest);
```

And the JSON is then stored in the database. Yippy yay. `manifest` is a complex object that contains a number of other objects and information that's used to created a final product. The problem is when we go to try to use that info to generate a new object. The FQN of the original class is stored with the information (makes sense). But the read back of the information is taking place in a different location/application. So while the original namespace that was stored with the json was type a.b.c.d.e.f.class1, we're now trying to read it back into class a.b.c.g.h.i.f.class1 ... logically class1 is the same in both namespacesses, in fact it was copied directly from one to the other. The only difference is the intervening package names.

Naturally, the when we then try to deserialize the JSON, it throws an error about not finding the type, the original type is in the original project/applicaiton and the "new" type is in the current project. We could reference the original app from the secondary app, but for functional reasons, we're trying to maintain decoupling between the two.

So the question is, how to get a serialized an object from one project and then deserialize it into another class that is logically identical?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Did my answer was helpful?

Comment: @MichałZiober - unfortunately due to time constraints I wasn't able to give your solution the full attention it would have needed to fit our needs, It also would have meant refactoring a number of classes and potentially affecting our plugin architecture. We ended up trying a number of things, but in the end, went for something "simple" yet a bit hacky - we're "DNA Splicing" by doing a String.Replace to change out the old namespace for the new namespace that we need in order to load the data. I know, I know. Not the best of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when typing is not used you can generate a `JSON` payload which you can later deserialise to any model which fits this `JSON`. Or even to `Map` or/and `List` objects if you do not want to create a model at all.

In your case, when `JSON` payloads are used by two different apps with two different models, you should not attach class info because it does not provide any extra information for another model. One `JSON` can be deserialised on many ways and used for different purposes so linking it with one model causes problems like you noticed in your example. So, if it is possible disable typing and provide explicitly all informations are needed later to recreate the same object from a `JSON`.

If it is not possible, just provide your custom `TypeIdResolver` and map one class from one model to similar class in another model. Simple example which shows an idea:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonTypeIdResolver;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.SimpleType;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule model2Module = new SimpleModule("Model2");
        model2Module.setMixInAnnotation(PojoA2.class, CustomJsonTypeIdResolverMixIn.class);
        model2Module.setMixInAnnotation(PojoB2.class, CustomJsonTypeIdResolverMixIn.class);
        model2Module.setMixInAnnotation(PojoC2.class, CustomJsonTypeIdResolverMixIn.class);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        mapper.registerModule(model2Module);

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new PojoA());

        System.out.println(json);

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, PojoA.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, PojoA2.class));
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM)
@JsonTypeIdResolver(value = Model2ClassNameIdResolver.class)
interface CustomJsonTypeIdResolverMixIn { }

class Model2ClassNameIdResolver extends ClassNameIdResolver {

    private final Map<String, JavaType> types = new HashMap<>();

    public Model2ClassNameIdResolver() {
        super(null, null);
        types.put("com.celoxity.PojoA", SimpleType.constructUnsafe(PojoA2.class));
        types.put("com.celoxity.PojoB", SimpleType.constructUnsafe(PojoB2.class));
        types.put("com.celoxity.PojoC", SimpleType.constructUnsafe(PojoC2.class));
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext context, String id) throws IOException {
        JavaType javaType = types.get(id);
        if (javaType != null) {
            return javaType;
        }

        return super.typeFromId(context, id);
    }
}

class PojoA2 {

    private PojoB2 b;
}

class PojoB2 {

    private List<PojoC2> c;
}

class PojoC2 {

    private String s;
    private int i;
}

class PojoA {

    private PojoB b;
}

class PojoB {

    private List<PojoC> c;
}

class PojoC {

    private String s;
    private int i;
}
```

Two models: `PojoA`, `PojoB`, `PojoC` and `PojoA2`, `PojoB2`, `PojoC2` have the same structure and have only different names. `PojoA` is the same as `PojoA2`, etc.

Above code prints:

```
["com.celoxity.PojoA",{"b":["com.celoxity.PojoB",{"c":["java.util.ArrayList",[["com.celoxity.PojoC",{"s":"Vika","i":22}]]]}]}]
```

and later:

```
PojoA{b=PojoB{c=[PojoC{s='Vika', i=22}]}}
PojoA2{b=PojoB2{c=[PojoC2{s='Vika', i=22}]}}
```